# testing firebase function with jest

Tags: typescript, firebase, jestjs, google-cloud-functions

Since two days I am trying to understand and write a test for my firebase function. For that test I just want to use the framework Jest. https://jestjs.io/

```
export const updateTipsPerFixture = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onUpdate((change) => {
    const beforeTips: Tip[] = change.before.data() !== undefined ? change.before.data().tips : [];
    const afterTips: Tip[] = change.after.data() !== undefined ? change.after.data().tips : [];

    if (JSON.stringify(beforeTips) === JSON.stringify(afterTips)) {
        return new Promise(resolve => resolve('equal'));
    }

    if (afterTips.length === beforeTips.length) {
        return new Promise(resolve => resolve('same length'));
    }

    if (beforeTips.length < afterTips.length) {
        return new Promise(resolve => resolve('afterTips.length is longer'));
    }

    return false;
});
```

Even after I read the Jest docu and cannot figure out how to mock/stub the firebase function module for my use case.

This is as far as I came. Yes, not really far.

```
describe('updateTipsPerFixture', () => {
    test('it should return true when tips are equal', () => {
        expect(updateTipsPerFixture).toEqual(new Promise(resolve => 'equal'));
    });
});
```

How should I write the test and mock the firebase module?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is pretty easy and nice. The function can be tested by calling the function run() and passing some data. See example:

```
describe('updateTipsPerFixture', () => {
    test('it should return true when tips are equal', () => {
        const mockedData = {
            before: {
                data(): FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | undefined {
                    return {tips: [{fixtureId: 123, teamId: 123} as Tip]}
                }
            },
            after: {
                data(): FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | undefined {
                    return {tips: [{fixtureId: 123, teamId: 123} as Tip]}
                }
            }
        } as Change<DocumentSnapshot>;

        const actual = updateTipsPerFixture.run(mockedData, null);

        return expect(actual).resolves.toEqual('equal');
    });
});
```